# Android Socket Connection Test

Tags: java, android, sockets

I'm trying to test if my Android App is connecting to a Rpi hot spot. I'm following [this guide](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/) for the client code.

I want to have a toast message pop up depending on the state of socket.isConnected() when I hit a button. However, I think each time I try and implement it, I run into Network on the main thread problems. How could I change the following code to add a simple "if(true), send toast message" using the isConnected method in the onClick?

Thank you for any help!

```
package mrxhaleenterprise.sockettest;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Socket socket;

private static final int SERVERPORT = 39169;
private static final String SERVER_IP = "172.24.1.1";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new Thread(new ClientThread()).start();
}

public void onClick(View view) {

    try {

        EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.EditText01);
        String str = et.getText().toString();
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                true);
        out.println(str);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

class ClientThread implements Runnable {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {
            InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

            socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVERPORT);

        } catch (UnknownHostException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

    }


}
}
```

Comment: can u share the error log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onClick` is called on main Thread.So you are writing to socket(Network Operation) on main thread which is causing problem. Your below code should run on background thread.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),
                    true);
            out.println(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to have a toast message pop up depending on the state of socket.isConnected() when I hit a button.

No you don't. Once you've constructed that `Socket`, it *is* connected, and that method won't magically start returning false if the connection goes down. You need to maintain your own state of the connection, depending on whether you've encountered an `IOException` or end of stream on it. More probably you don't want the button at all, you want to pop up an error dialogue *when the disconnect happens*.